# MySQL Syntax Error Exception when executing Update query

Tags: java, mysql

I'm getting the message

```
"MySQLSyntaxErrorExcetpion You have an error in your SQL syntax."
```

I'm following a tutorial online and I don't see what's anything different with my code and the code I'm following. Can anyone point out where I went wrong?

Let me know if additional information is needed.

[image: Screenshot]

```
btn_update.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try{
                    theQuery("update users set fname = '" + firstNameField.getText() + "', lname = '" + lastNameField.getText() +"', age=" + ageField.getText() + "where id = " + idField.getText());
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                    }

            }
        });
```

Comment: You've missed a space character before "where"

Comment: Mandatory comment: This code is wide open to SQL-injection attacks. Consider using a `PreparedStatement` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you don't have spaces here:

```
age=" + ageField.getText() + "where id = " + idField.getText());
```

You need to change it to

```
age= " + ageField.getText() + " where id = " + idField.getText());
```

I advice to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of the native way

Comment: I was so close! lol I'll try prepared statement next time thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a space in front of " where id = ".
That should work

Answer (score 0):

Use toString() function to convert values to string and then pass them to query, as follow:

```
firstNameField.getText().toString()
```